# Unused package dependency not building when deploying shiny app

Tags: r, shinyapps

I'm attempting to deploy my shiny app to shinyapps.io but I'm getting a build  error for gWidgetstcltk (0.0-55). gWidgets is a dependency for one of the packages I use in my app. However, I only use a few functions from this package that don't require gWidgets.

I tried deploying on Windows and Ubuntu with no success. I tried installing TK8.5 (required for gWidgetstcltk) but this did not help any. Ideally if there was a way I can force the app to build without this dependency the app should still work. Alternatively, is there a way I could remove this dependency from the package itself?

Error message:

```
Warning: no DISPLAY variable so Tk is not available
Error in structure(.External(.C_dotTclObjv, objv), class = "tclObj") : 
  [tcl] invalid command name "font".

Error : unable to load R code in package ‘gWidgetstcltk’
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘gWidgetstcltk’
* removing ‘/opt/R/3.4.4/lib/R/library/gWidgetstcltk’
################################# End Task Log ################################# 
Error: Unhandled Exception: Child Task 643000037 failed: Error building image: Error building gWidgetstcltk (0.0-55). Build exited with non-zero status: 1
```

Comment: It doesn't matter if you don't use the majority of functions from it, the package build won't work. (Said differently: I don't know if you can force binary install of packages on shinyapps.io or somehow override this build behavior.) If the functions you need are not significant, can you copy them into your own code/package/app and remove the package dependency? (It is recommended to cite the package and version so that (1) you aren't pretending you wrote it, and (2) you can update/troubleshoot when something happens.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Without a fix to the gWidgetstcltk build issue I'm afraid I will have to only include the functions I use. That is a good tip, and I'll definitely to make sure to properly cite the package.